# openxlsx::saveWorkbook -- write error during file append

Tags: r, error-handling, xlsx, openxlsx

I have a script that has been running smoothly for months. The last line of code basically goes as follows:

```
saveWorkbook(Wb, 'address/filename.xlsx'), overwrite = TRUE)
```

I run this script weekly (Mondays, unimportant), so I go to run it this week and I'm now getting this error when I go to save this created workbook:

Warning message:
In file.append(to[okay], from[okay]) : write error during file append

The address for this file is on a shared drive for work, so one of my first thoughts was maybe there were some new permissions for the shared drive, since saving this on local drives seems okay. But, I can save csv files on the shared drive still (using data.table::fwrite).

I'm a bit at a loss here. I've updated R, RTools, and RStudio and all my packages.

Has anyone come across this, or a similar, issue before? I could possibly be looking for some more information concerning the "write error during file append". I'm actually creating a whole new file when I run this and not appending anything to an existing file. But, I haven't been able to find anything explaining situations that could cause this error.

Comment: How many rows are in the data? Could you be exceeding Excel's limit?

Comment: Great question, but that shouldn't be the/an issue. It's a problem I've now encountered (this week) with multiple reports I put together using R to create Excel workbooks that doesn't get anywhere near the row limit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same output but only inside a blob container on azure

overwrite instruction fails

```
packageVersion("openxlsx")
[1] ‘4.2.5’
>  openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx")
>  openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx")
Warning message:
In file.append(to[okay], from[okay]) : write error during file append
>  openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx",overwrite = T)
Warning message:
In file.append(to[okay], from[okay]) : write error during file append
>  openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx",overwrite = F)
Error in saveWorkbook(wb, file = file, overwrite = overwrite) : 
  File already exists!
```

Same code on my desktop produces diferent output

```
> packageVersion("openxlsx")
[1] ‘4.2.5’
> openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx")
> openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx")
> openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx",overwrite = T)
> openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx",overwrite = F)
Error in saveWorkbook(wb, file = file, overwrite = overwrite) : 
  File already exists!
```

As we can't fix Azure I recomend delete first and the write

```
> filexls= "mtcars.xlsx"
> if (file.exists(filexls)) {
+   file.remove(filexls)
+ }
[1] TRUE
> openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars,file ="mtcars.xlsx",overwrite = T)
```